# Why FirstName, LastName, Company field not found in FieldPermission query result?

Tags: permissions, leads, fields, permission-sets, field-level-security

I'm trying to get all fields and its read and write permission using below query

SELECT Field, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions WHERE SObjectType ='Lead' AND parentId IN ( SELECT permissionSetId FROM PermissionSetAssignment where assigneeId IN('#assignee_Id #'))

I'm getting expected result :

[image]

But still some fields are missing in the output like "FirstName, LastName, Company, Street, City, Country..."

assignee_Id is System Administrator and having Field-Level access to all fields.

Facing same issue with Account and Contact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FieldPermissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_FieldPermissions.htm) represents the enabled field permissions for the parent Permission Set. It's not a representation of everything that someone has access to.

The fields you identified: `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Street`, etc are fields that Salesforce sets access to.

You'll notice, within a permission set, that when you set `Object Settings` for `Lead`, those fields aren't included (meaning they're not permissionable).

You can see this another way through the `fields` property of [DescribeSObjectResults](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm) (or through workbench explorer). A field has a property called **permissionable**

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Schema.SObjectType.Lead.fields.FirstName;
System.debug(dfr.isPermissionable()); //returns false
```

> Indicates whether FieldPermissions can be specified for the field
> (true) or not (false).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @kris-goncalves

Answer (score 2):

Fields that are database required (e.g. Name), and fields that are "compound fields" (e.g. City) are not included in the field level security fields. The former are always required and therefore don't need to be checked for access, while the latter are turned on/off at the compound field level (e.g. Address contains City).